# How to add woocmmerce product feature description (Attributes) like Samsung

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, e-commerce, customization

I am having a problem to add **feature description** (Attributes) something like Samsung feature table. Like this:

[image]

If I add attributes generally it shows like that:

[image]

I am looking forward to a WP plugin (free) or easy customization (adding code). I tied with Advanced custom fields (Plugin) but I couldn't show under feature table.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're looking to group attributes, you can do it with [this plugin](https://welaunch.io/plugins/woocommerce-group-attributes/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I am looking for free plugin or customizing code. Since it's my experiment of learning so I don't need premium plugin.